# Choose directory of site folder (www) uwamp

Tags: uwamp

I installed uwamp to deploy in my company and I have a question.

Can I setting up uwamp to move the site folder (www) in Appdata/roaming for each active directory user work on own site and can retrieve if they change computer ?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can search and replace the string {DOCUMENTPATH} with your desired path in the apache config file under

```
UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\httpd_uwamp.conf
```

Example:

search and replace {DOCUMENTPATH}/ with C:\www/